# Spring security and REST API login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have backend in spring-boot, exposing REST API, and i have SEPARATED front end in react.

I want to use spring security to secure my back end, and i want to keep spring authentication chain. However, when i use configuration such as:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .cors().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/newUser").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()          
                .formLogin().pertmitAll();
    }
```

This generates `/login` endpoint and every request that is not authorized will get redirected to `login` page. However spring generates this `/login` login page and as i said i have my own stand-alone fornt-end in REACT, so i do not want spring to generate this page, i want it to tell my client to redirect to `/login`. If i disable `formLogin`

`.formLogin().disable()`

then i also lose my `/login` POST endpoint, and springs default authentication process.

Is there a way to keep to `/login` POST endpoint but remove the `login` page and let my frond-end client to redirect.

Thanks for help!

Comment: several things why do you have a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` when there is already one built into spring security. You should remove this and use the default built in one and customize the built in one to your needs if you have something crazy. Second you can implement a https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html and return a 302 FOUND response, with a Location header pointing to your login page.

Comment: Hi. How is your client supposed to authenticate against your backend? Basic auth, Bearer token, etc. I assume your authenticationFilter() plays a role here? If so, it would be nice if you could include its code.

Comment: @Johnyb please add the code you're currently have for authenticationFilter()

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Toerktumlare 100%. You really should use the default implementations that Spring Security Framework offers and if you really need to add additional configuration that cannot be passed by values, then you should extend the original Spring Security Class.

In this case, you just have to specify the endpoint where your login page is:

```
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/yourLoginPage.html")
.loginProcessingUrl("/doLgin")
.defaultSuccessUrl("/yourHomePahe.html", true)
```

Comment: The question clearly says that the login page will be built in a SEPARATE front end in react. 
What is /yourLoginpage.html about?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the **GET** method, you will get html page. As I understand you need **POST** API call, [Post API call to get JWT access_tocken and refresh tocken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UayoR.png)

you can use "/login" as API in **post** call to send a username and password; in response, you will get a token or anything that you send after successful authentication.